# Running an or tools example in maven

Tags: or-tools

I am trying to run an example in an IDE with the latest maven support in or-tools. After cmake build completion(instructions from [here](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/cmake/doc/java.md)) I am able to see the jar file in my .m2 folder. I added the following dependency to my project

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.ortools</groupId>
        <artifactId>ortools-java</artifactId>
        <version>7.7.7810</version>
    </dependency>
```

It compiles successfully, but while running the program it throws the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniortools in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at com.walmartlabs.services.core.engine.ortools.OrToolSolver.<clinit>(OrToolSolver.java:13)
```

Shouldn't adding the dependency be enough why does it need an external library sample program below.

```
 public class OrToolSolver {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("jniortools");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create the linear solver with the CBC backend.
        MPSolver solver = new MPSolver("SimpleMipProgram", MPSolver.OptimizationProblemType.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING);
    }
```

I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: I would believe you need to tell maven where to load the jni library. something like java.library.path on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, we do not support maven, we do not build any maven jar. It is in the plan.

Answer (score 0):

Add [this](https://github.com/oliviercailloux/google-or-tools-java) as a dependency. That will make your life easier when trying to build OR-tools via Maven.